# How to Fix Document Not Found errors with find

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection of Person, stored in a legacy mongodb server (2.4) and accessed with the mongoid gem via the ruby mongodb driver.

If I perform a

```
    Person.where(email: 'some.existing.email@server.tld').first
```

I get a result (let's assume I store the id in a variable called "the_very_same_id_obtained_above")

If I perform a

```
    Person.find(the_very_same_id_obtained_above)
```

I got a

```
    Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
```

exception

If I use the javascript syntax to perform the query, the result is found

```
   Person.where("this._id == #{the_very_same_id_obtained_above}").first # this works!
```

I'm currently trying to migrate the data to a newever version. Currently mongodbrestore-ing on amazon documentdb to make tests (mongodb 3.6 compatible) and the issue remains.

One thing I noticed is that those object ids are peculiar:

5ce24b1169902e72c9739ff6 this works anyway

59de48f53137ec054b000004 this requires the trick

The small number of zeroes toward the end of the id seems to be highly correlated with the problem (I have no idea of the reason).

Comment: You say:

>     Person.find(the_very_same_id_obtained_above)

However, `the_very_same_id_obtained_above` is not defined anywhere in your question.

Comment: It is referred to the id of the person found in the first query

Comment: Most likely you made a mistake in your code somewhere and are not querying for the IDs returned by the database. Maybe there are unexpected type conversions involved. Another possibility is you are using other old software which has bugs. IDs can be generated by the application and are not required to be in a particular format. Consider creating a small but complete reproduce case illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default:

```
 # Raise an error when performing a #find and the document is not found.
 # (default: true)
 raise_not_found_error: true
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config

If this doesn't answer your question, it's very likely the `find` method is overridden somewhere in your code!